# Loop localstorage and display complete list of all key and value in ionic app

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework, local-storage

I have saved multiple keys and value in localStorage as below:

```
Day1  1
Day2  2
Day3  3
```

I want to retrieve all the keys and values and display them in a list view.

My home.html looks like below:

```
<ion-item-divider >
<ion-label >{{key}} </ion-label>
<ion-label color="secondary">{{value}}</ion-label>    
</ion-item-divider>
```

My home.ts looks like below:

```
for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
      this.key = localStorage.key(i);
      console.log(this.key);
      this.value = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));
      console.log(this.value);
    }
```

I am able to display only the last record. Please suggest where i am doing wrong.

Comment: all your keys are named `Day`? if so then that wont work

Comment: I have corrected. Its Day1, Day2, Day3

Comment: well is this ionic component included in a `map` operator function? because if its not, your loop is working but its overwriting one variable hence you see only one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to resolve the issue using follow query.

home.ts is as below:

```
allObj: any[] = [];
for ( var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; ++i ) {
      this.result1 = localStorage.key( i );
      this.result2 = localStorage.getItem( localStorage.key( i ) );
      this.result3 = this.result1 + " " + this.result2;
      var y = this.result3;
      console.log(y);
      this.allObj.push(this.result3);
    }
```

home.html is as below:

```
<ion-item no-lines text-wrap *ngFor="let item of allObj" >
<p>{{item}}</p>
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyvalue pipe in the *ngFor.

```
<ion-item-divider *ngFor="let item of mainObject|keyvalue">
  <ion-label>{{item.key}} </ion-label>
  <ion-label color="secondary">{{item.value}}</ion-label>
</ion-item-divider>
```

In your TS file:

```
mainObject = {...localStorage};
(or)
mainObject = {};
for (const key in localStorage) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(localStorage, key)) {
          this.mainObject[key] = localStorage[key];
      }
    }
```

Angular Documentation : https://angular.io/api/common/KeyValuePipe#description

Comment: @BongaigaonGapps can you share output of console.log(localStorage) ?